# How to calculate the length of the landcover types a path crosses in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, land-cover

I have a path which represents a proposed pipeline route.  I need to find the length of the various landcovers the route crosses.  Not area within a buffer.  I found a ArcGIS help topic that kinda shows what I want to do: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Overlay_analysis

Is this the best way to do it? ie- convert raster to vector, overlay vector and line?

EDIT- the land cover file is a raster file.

Comment: What type of data is your landcover? If it is vector-data i would not convert anything and just use the tool "intersect".

Comment: It's a raster file.  I've been trying to convert it to a vector, but I've been having issues.  Not sure if it's the size of the file or something with my QGIS installation.

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool intersect. Then in the new vector layer with the intersected lines add a field in the table with the "field calculator". In the new field specify `$length` as expression and be sure that the new field is a **real** variable.
After the calculation will be easy to calculate what you need with MS Excel, just export the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the tool "Sum line length".

When you have vector-polygons and vector-lines, this tool will produce a new polygon-layer with an additional attribute --> the line length within the polygon.